# sns.catplot - how can i make my legend bigger?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I have this code:

```
ax = sns.catplot(x='account_name', y='cnt', hue='threat_campaigns',data=df_mitigation,kind='bar', height=15, aspect=3.1, palette='coolwarm' )
ax.fig.suptitle("Accounts' violations disribuation over the last week", fontsize=40)
plt.yscale("log")


plt.xlabel('Account', fontsize=40)
plt.ylabel('Number of requests', fontsize=40)
plt.setp(ax._legend.get_title(), fontsize=40)

plt.show()
```

see what i get as in screenshot - everything is very small - how can i make it bigger.[image]

Comment: You may want to make your figure smaller ... you are asking for a figure that is about  15 inches high and 45 inches wide. The default font sizes will work better for figures closer to the default size.

Comment: @meitale , did I answer your question. Please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to the solution.

Comment: Here is how to accept an answer. Upvoting is also appreciated: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can update the `rcParams` dictionary using an example like `with sns.plotting_context(rc={"legend.fontsize":24, "legend.title_fontsize":24}):`.

Reproducible example.

```
df = sns.load_dataset('flights')
with sns.plotting_context(rc={"legend.fontsize":24, "legend.title_fontsize":24}):
    ax = sns.catplot(x='year', y='passengers', hue='month', data=df, kind='bar', height=15, aspect=3.1, palette='coolwarm')
    plt.show()
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]